# sending and receiving json objects from old asmx webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, asmx

I have a reference to an external asmx webservice which is emitting soap xml. How to consume using asp.net client to send and receive json objects. Limited to .net framework version 3.5. Please share code snippets.

We can't change anything from webservice side since it is external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[WebService]
[ScriptService]
public class MyWebService : WebService
{    
  [WebMethod (Description="doc here")]    
  [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=false, ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]     
  public MyObjectType responseMyObject() 
  {
      Proxy pu = new Proxy(...);
      return pu.GetMyObject();
  }
}
```

You dont need a `JSON serializer`, tagging it with the ScriptService attribute gives it tie ability to serialize JSON out. You were pre serializing the JSON and then serializing it again :(

Comment: We can't change anything from webservice side since it is external.

Comment: @john, you cant add new methods?

Comment: @nathangonzalez We are consuming an external asmx webservice

Comment: @john, so you don't actually 'have' the service.  there is no way to change the output of an asmx file from the client.  you could write an intermediary that consumes the xml and translates it to json, but i'm not sure that's really worth it.